# Integration using a Gamma Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I want to find the following integral.

$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha) \beta^\alpha} \int^{\infty}_{5} (x-5)^{a-1} e^{tx} e^{- \frac{x-5}{\beta}} dx$$

Based on some research I have done, I believe that it could be a good idea to use the gamma function, but I am unsure how to exactly use it to solve the integral in this case. How would I go about this?

Comment: Hint: first, introduce the change of integration variable from $x$ to $u$ by $u=x-5$. Second, change from $u$ to $s$ by $s = \left( {\frac{1}{\beta } - t} \right)u$. Note that theres should be some restrictions on the various parameters for this integral to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int_5^\infty(x-5)^{\alpha-1}e^{tx}e^{-(x-5)/\beta}dx$$
$u=x-5$, $du=dx$
$$I=e^{5t}\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-1}e^{tu}e^{-u/\beta}du=e^{5t}\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\beta^{-1}-t)u}du=e^{5t}\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-1}e^{-\gamma u}du$$
for ease I am going to get $\gamma=\beta^{-1}-t$ then we will need to make the substitution $v=\gamma u$ $dv=\gamma du$ and so:
$$I=e^{5t}\gamma^{2-\alpha}\int_0^\infty v^{\alpha-1}e^{-v}dv=e^{5t}\gamma^{2-\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)=e^{5t}\left(\frac1\beta-t\right)^{2-\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)$$
now you should be able to do the rest pretty easily

Comment: Why is it $e^{5t}$ outside the integral? Shouldn't it be $e^{(u + 5)t}$ @HenryLee?

Comment: So I presume it would have to move back inside the integral then... @Henry Lee

Comment: actually isn't $t$ a constant so it doesnt matter where it is placed? @325 that is probably why I did it

Comment: could you fix your answer?

Comment: The original integral is wrt x so t is a constant regardless. The answer is correct